# React Native Drawer Dependencies

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-cli

Can somebody send a screenshot of the dependencies needed to run Drawer component in react native

Ps. it will help better if its a screenshot of packages.json

Thanks!

Comment: Check out the drawer navigator of react-navigation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation/

Comment: I tried but never worked

Comment: @Moistbobo Please Help!

Comment: please check @Amila ive added steps below

Answer (score 1):

Ill go step by step:

1.`yarn add @react-navigation/native`
2.`yarn add react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context`

> If you're on a Mac and developing for iOS, you need to install the
> pods (via Cocoapods) to complete the linking.
>
> `npx pod-install ios` react-native-screens package requires one
> additional configuration step to properly work on Android devices.
> Edit MainActivity.java file which is located in
> `android/app/src/main/java/<your package name>/MainActivity.java.`
>
> Add the following code to the body of MainActivity class:
>
> @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
> super.onCreate(null); } and make sure to add an import statement at
> the top of this file:
>
> `import android.os.Bundle`; This change is required to avoid crashes
> related to View state being not persisted consistently across Activity
> restarts.

Then
3.`yarn add @react-navigation/drawer`
4.`yarn add react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated`

Final step:
To finalize installation of react-native-gesture-handler, add the following at the top (make sure it's at the top and there's nothing else before it) of your entry file, such as index.js or App.js:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```